# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios-provisioning

Hello I'm trying to archive an iOS app. I get this:

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Breakout_Infinity-flobgciszuktcrbcwbotdnurdubv/ArchiveIntermediates/Breakout Infinity/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Breakout Infinity.app/Breakout Infinity
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Breakout_Infinity-flobgciszuktcrbcwbotdnurdubv/ArchiveIntermediates/Breakout Infinity/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Breakout Infinity.app: valid on disk
/Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Breakout_Infinity-flobgciszuktcrbcwbotdnurdubv/ArchiveIntermediates/Breakout Infinity/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Breakout Infinity.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: failed to satisfy code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed to execute codesign(1)
 - (null)
```

The certificate is valid, the distribution provisioning profile is OK. It just wont sign. The build settings select the distribution profile. Everything is as it should be.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As of the past few days a lot of develops are having this problem. I believe it has to do with newly created or renewed distribution certificates. They just don't work. Like you, I'm 99.9% sure I've followed all the steps required to sign apps, and get the same error. I've done this at least 15 times before successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to remember what went wrong here. I think I just had to go through the entire certificate/profiling process again because it changed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

My app suddenly got this error during pre-submit validation process, a week ago I just submitted a build on the same machine same settings without any problem.

Wasted half an hour on this problem on googling, eventually I managed fixed it by creating a new dist profile and rebuild.

I doubt my old app's signature was corrupted, as mentioned in [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32)